# ng-show expression not updating after variable update

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I have a controller which prints some data in a `ul` using a `ng-repeat`. Each `li` is divided in two parts:

```
<li>
   <div>
       <button type="button" class="some classes" ng-show="!field.edit.state" ng-click="field.edit.update(true)">Edit</button>
      <button type="button" class="some classes" ng-show="field.edit.state" ng-click="field.edit.update(false)">Save</button>
  {{field.title}}
  </div>
  <div ng-show="field.edit.state">
      <input />
  </div>
```

The idea is, when the "Edit" button is clicked the `input` field and the "Save" button are shown, while the "Edit" button itself is hidden. Clicking on the "Save" button goes on the other way around. Since I need to execute some functions on the start and the end of the editing the `update` also triggers some callbacks from my controller. Now, the callbacks are correcly triggered, the state is updated, but nothing changes on my page.

The update function code is pretty simple:

```
  function registerEdit(callback){
      var state = false;

      var update = function(newState){
         state = newState;
         callback(newState)
         $timeout(function(){
             $scope.$apply()
         })
      }

      return {
         state : state,
         update : update
     }
}
```

Each field element is injected its own `registerEdit` property when the data are fetched from the server and injected in the `$scope`, so they are unique (I've checked that part, and it works). From what I know about Angular, after changing the `$scope` all I needed to do was to call the `$apply` function to have Angular change my view, but even as the state changes (I logged it) the display remains the same.

Comment: I don't understand how you pass your variable to the view/template do you put it in the $scope or "this" (var vm = this ) ?

Comment: I'll edit the question to explain it

Comment: Have you traced this and verified the code is actually being called when the buttons are clicked?

Comment: Yes. Every callback is executed and the variables are updated correctly

Comment: Your `state` is only returned once when you call `registerEdit()`, but not after each update.